# Facebook Graph API checkins

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a check-in in user's feed, using offline access. But I keep getting various errors, but if i try to post message/video/picture everything works great.

So here is my code:

```
public function postCheckIn()
{
    $post=array(
        'access_token'=>  $this->token,
        'message'=>'Test check-in!',
        'place'=>'172822562765332',
        'coordinates' => json_encode(array(
               'latitude'  => '55.772855818478',
               'longitude' => '37.687225341797'
             ))
    );
    try
    {
        $res=$this->fb->api('/'.$this->uid.'/checkins', 'POST', $post);
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        $res=$e->getMessage();
    }
    return $res;
}
```

When I'm running this code, I get an exception:

> Requires a valid Place Page ID

I check this place using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/, and it returns some valid info.

BTW, I have publish_checkins permission.

Do I always have to provide placeId, and coordinates? Can I provide one of this parameters?
And how to get it to work?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't checkin to Facebook Places by post to api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697603/cant-checkin-to-facebook-places-by-post-to-api)

Comment: Yes, I saw that post, but it doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/172822562765332 doesn't have latitude longitude data
i suppose that's why

this is a snippet that work... your params looks correct to me 
        formPost->addField("message",message );
        formPost->addField("place",place);
        formPost->addField("coordinates",coordinates);
        formPost->addField("tags",tags );
        formPost->addField("application","{\"id\": \"204264309603362\",\"name\": \"mobile borg\"}");
        qDebug()<<"FacebookGraph::post"<

```
    QString feed=url+"me/checkins";
```

Comment: Yes, you were right. It's actually pretty complicated to get correct id for place. I found correct id, and now everything works fine. But still, I don't understand why I have to provide both place, and coordinates, why I can't provide just place.

Comment: you have to live with how Facebook works :) maybe you will find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017790/can-a-developer-add-places-to-facebook-checkin

Comment: to find places you have to use search?type=place

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the publish_stream as this will get around any issues you are having with offline publishing.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/